# find boundary coordinates of image in matlab

Tags: javascript, matlab, math, matrix

I want to find boundary points (co-ordinates) of any image.starting from any point traverse counter-clockwise and store co-ordinates.
let's say I have the following image. I want to extract the edges coordinates and save them in m file, so that I can use these points to sketch the shape in excel.

[leaf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znhqJ.jpg)

Comment: Please post some code to let us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert your image to binary image and fill holes.
Then use [bwperim](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html?s_tid=doc_ta) function can find the perimeter. Then use find to get the coordinates.

For example(Suppose your image is pic):

```
pic_g = 255 - rgb2gray(pic);
BW = imbinarize(pic_g);
BW2 = imfill(BW,'holes');
perimeter = bwperim(BW2);
[row,col] = find(perimeter) ;
```

'row'、'col' is the coordinates of perimeter.

Comment: This does not fufill OPs request for points to be in order counter-clockwise around the object

Comment: thank you brother 张庆昊 for ur help. But when i use your code, then i copied row and col then paste them in excel i got the whole image ( not the boundary). i want only the boundary of the image to appear. 
please help me...

Comment: After run this code, I got two mat 'row' and 'col', which size is  3716×1, and your picture' size is 1200×1600. If it cotains whole image, it's size should be 1920000×1.

Comment: If you want a result in order counter-clockwise, you should implement a special function 'find' to achieve it. I don't think there is any code in matlab to implement it, or you can try to find in github, but I don't sure it exist.